# trouble using reduce to this function

Tags: python

```
sum_of_squares = lambda L: sum([x**2 for x in L])
#reduce(sum_of_squares,[1])

assert sum_of_squares([2,3,4]) == 29
assert sum_of_squares([]) == 0
assert sum_of_squares([1]) == 1
```

What I have commented out is my attempt at using reduce, isn't that the right format? reduce(function,sequence). Not sure what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: reduce takes a function of *two arguments*, not a function that already reduces an entire input list. With a function like `sum_of_squares`, which takes an entire input list and reduces it itself, you don't need `reduce`.

Comment: Note that the reducer function should have two arguments: the result so far, and the next value. It doesn't take the whole list. To do sum of squares with `reduce` you'd want `lambda x, y: x + y ** 2`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Except that that doesn't square the first number. While you could patch the problem with a `start` argument, it'd be much cleaner to use `map` for the squaring transformation and `reduce` for the sum.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, you'd need to explicitly set the start of `0`. Frankly I think what the OP already has makes more sense than a `reduce` version.

Comment: your lambda function already behaves like a reducer, trying to wrap it in another reducer would complicate things, no?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to implement `sum_of_squares` as a `reduce`. I'm not sure what you are attempting to do with `reduce(sum_of_square, ...)`:

If the former then you can implement it:

```
>>> import functools as ft
>>> import operator as op
>>> sum_of_squares = lambda L: ft.reduce(op.add, map(lambda x: x**2, L), 0)
>>> assert sum_of_squares([2,3,4]) == 29
>>> assert sum_of_squares([]) == 0
>>> assert sum_of_squares([1]) == 1
```

But the `sum(x**2 for x in L)` does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` will take two elements , apply function , take the result and apply to next element and so on until end of list. Hence, in your case answer will be incorrect.

You may want to map square function to the list and then sum it up as follows,

```
l = [2,3,4]

print sum((map(lambda x : x**2 ,l)))
>>> 
29
>>>
```

Comment: @AChampion , Yes I noticed that. removed from answer. Thanks for pointing out.